# Whats the best way to send multiple variables in a query string within a URL

Tags: php, string, url, variables

I have a client who is wanting to create a link which contains product codes so that his customers hit a page with just those products displayed in an attempt to increase conversion rates from affilliate sites.

My question is whats the best way to send these multiple products in a single URL

For example:

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bespoke-list.php?catNo=234-324-232-343

Obviously then the site would grab the codes from the string and display them...

We're going to be using PHP!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly send the like you described, with `-` as separator. The querystring variables are stored in the [$_GET](http://php.net/$_GET) array in PHP, so your example numbers can be accessed like this:

```
$ids = $_GET['catNo'];
$ids = explode('-', $ids);
foreach($ids as $id) {
  echo "<p>$id</p>"; //Do something with $id here.
}
```

Another way could be to store them directly as an array in the querystring, like this:

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/bespoke-list.php?id[]=234&id[]=324&id[]=232&id[]=343

Then you can get the ids directly without explode:

```
$ids = $_GET['id'];
foreach($ids as $id) {
  echo "<p>$id</p>"; //Do something with $id here.
}
```

But when I look at it, the first one is certainly a more attractive URL. :-)

Comment: Thats what i was thinking :)  About attractive URL.  And also easier to give over to clients so they understand it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make URL look better, you could do it by using `.htaccess` file.

Comment: definitely, for this task though we're not bothered about SEO and its quicker to write product codes, but valid point!

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the query string with a prefix for each product "**catNo-**" as follows:

**catNo-1**=234&**catNo-2**=324&**catNo-3**=232&**catNo-4**=343

The php code to parse the above query string:

```
<?php
$catNoPrefix = "catNo-";
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    if("FALSE" != strstr($key, $catNoPrefix )) {
        $idValue = $_GET[$key];
        echo "<p>$idValue</p>"; 
    }
}
?>
```